# How do I unload a record from the Ember Data store if I don't have the record

Tags: ember-data

I am using Ember Data revision 8 and calling the "find" method on the store with an ID.
If the server does not find a record for this ID then I'm not sure how to let my controllers and views know.

The find method in the adapter does not receive an instance of the record so if the server returns an empty hash I can not access the record's state manager to transition it into another state.

I was looking at the Store and did not see any method I could call directly from my adapter to say "Hey I did not find a record with this ID for this Type. Move it [record in the record cache] out of loading into deleted". I guess I could call Store.load(...) to transition the record but this sounds like a dirty workaround.

At the moment, the record's "isLoaded" computed property will always be false which means that if I implement some kind of spinner based on this property then it will just hang.

Has anyone faced this before?

Thanks